# don't wan't insert null data in c# form

Tags: c#, sql, forms, null

I made a SQL Data Base and a C# Form. Form is work correctly. When i send data from the form, the data insert to the table correctly. But I have tried, if the form is only one field or empty, do not send the data to the table.I prepared not allowed the null data in the table fields. But other than the primary key, i can insert to null data for the other fields.

This is my main form code. Please correct it

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
        txtPasswordNew.PasswordChar = '*';
        gboxSignup.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnOrSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gboxSignup.Visible = true;

    }

    private void btnSignupNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFirstNameNew.Text != null && txtLasyNameNew.Text != null && txtUserNameNew.Text != null && txtPasswordNew.Text != null && txtEmailNew.Text != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Connect obj = new Connect();
                obj.conn.ConnectionString = obj.locate;
                obj.conn.Open();
                String insertUser = "insert into userTable values ('"+txtFirstNameNew.Text+ "','" +txtLasyNameNew.Text+ "','" +txtEmailNew.Text+ "','" +txtUserNameNew.Text+ "','" +txtPasswordNew.Text+"')";
                obj.cmd.Connection = obj.conn;
                obj.cmd.CommandText = insertUser;
                obj.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Signup has been completed");
                gboxSignup.Visible = false;
                txtFirstNameNew.Text = "";
                txtLasyNameNew.Text = "";
                txtEmailNew.Text = "";
                txtPasswordNew.Text = "";
                txtUserNameNew.Text = "";



            }   
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR!!!  Fill in the All Fields");
        }
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtUserName.Text != null && txtPassword.Text != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Connect obj = new Connect();
                obj.conn.ConnectionString = obj.locate;

                obj.conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter ("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM userTable where UserName = '" +txtUserName.Text+"' and Password = '"+txtPassword.Text+"' ", selectConnection: obj.conn );
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    frmWelcome meLoad = new frmWelcome();
                    meLoad.Visible = true;
                    this.Hide();
                    MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Login");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("User Name Or Password is incorrect - Try it");
                }
                obj.conn.Close();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Empty Field Allowed");
        }
    }
}
```

}

this is connect class code

```
class Connect
{
    public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    public SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    public string locate = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='J:\D Drive\Excersize\C#\Windowsform\WindowsFormsApp1\UserDB.mdf';Integrated Security=True";

}
```

this is my table design (userTable)
[image]

this is after insert data. 
[image]

this is my form design
[image]

insert can null data
[image]

insert data try to no primary key[image]

Comment: It seems you are trying to insert a row with a duplicated PK, have you tried with other values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string of text box is not null, it just empty. So the database could insert it.
Use `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)` instead `text != null`

Comment: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstNameNew.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLasyNameNew.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmailNew.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserNameNew.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPasswordNew.Text))  i am try this. i am fill all fields. can't submit. comes error massage

Comment: @TipVisor You forgot the `!` aka `NOT` operator bro.

Comment: It should
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstNameNew.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text2)....)

Comment: oh.. i corected it. I switched the if & else actions. thank you. it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtFirstNameNew.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtLasyNameNew.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtUserNameNew.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtPasswordNew.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtEmailNew.Text))
```

string.IsNullOrEmpty doesn't pick up the case if there is any whitespace characters in the text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to your data:

Your primary key is the "First Name" column

Your first row has someone with a blank "First Name", with last name "tharaka".

Because you cannot repeat a Primary Key, that means you can't have another row with a blank "First Name"

So in your image which shows the error, you are trying to put in a blank "First Name", which is not allowed.

So to solve your issue, just make sure "First Name" always has a value. Otherwise you will have to remove it as a Primary Key column.

This also means you can't have two rows with the same "First Name". I would sugges you add an ID field, with an autoincrementing integer as your Primary Key